# Unable to create 'launch.json' file inside the '.vscode' folder ({0})

Tags: linux, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm on a linux machine running vscode.  I am trying to do some debugging but whenever I try to select the environment configuration I get the message, "Unable to create 'launch.json' file inside the '.vscode' folder ({0})."

I suspect it could be a permissions thing but when I try to run vscode as an elevated user I am warned not to.  Instead it advises that I can change the user data directory.  Will this fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, it turns out that the .vscode directory is created inside the root folder of each project added to vscode.  To resolve the problem I had to create the folder manually and give permissions for vscode to write to the directory.